# GWT Hyperlink Focus acts like Active on CSS

Tags: html, css, gwt, hyperlink, focus

Well I've been working with some GWT code...

I'm trying to apply some Style to my Template, but when I apply CSS to Hyperlink on it, I find that a:focus method is acting as a:active, I mean it's just lasting while I press on Hyperlink but if I double click on the same Hyperlink it magically works!, I've tried with Anchor widget, but if I do this I must rewrite a lot of code and can't use History with it

I made an hypothesis about what's happening, not sure if wrong or right, I believe that as GWT uses AJAX it simply refreshes the page

```
.Template-link
{
    COLOR: #ab1e2c;
FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
LINE-HEIGHT: 43px;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
}
.Template-link a:focus
{
    COLOR: green !important;
}
```

So, do you have any idea of what's happening in here?

thanks in advance

---

More code (from Public Template)

```
package com.test.web.ui;

import com.foboa.fbwt.user.client.Page;
import com.foboa.fbwt.user.client.Template;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.History;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DockPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasVerticalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasVerticalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Anchor;

import com.test.web.client.Item;
import com.test.web.client.css.TestCssBundle;
import com.test.web.client.constants.TestConstants;
import com.test.web.client.images.IconBundle;

@Singleton
public class PublicTemplate extends Template {

private final DockPanel main = new DockPanel();

private final IconBundle iconBundle;

private final TestConstants constants;

private final TestCssBundle cssBundle;

@Inject
private PublicTemplate(IconBundle iconBundle, TestConstants constants,
           TestCssBundle cssBundle) {
this.iconBundle = iconBundle;
this.constants = constants;
    this.cssBundle = cssBundle;
}

@Override
public final void loadPage() {
Page page = getPage();
main.add(page, DockPanel.CENTER);
main.setCellHorizontalAlignment(page,
                HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
}

@Override
public final void loadTemplate(){
main.setWidth("100%");
setWidget(main);
loadHeader();
loadFooter();
}

private void loadFooter(){
//create footer panel
HorizontalPanel footerPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
footerPanel.setWidth("100%");
//include footer content
main.add(footerPanel, DockPanel.SOUTH); 
}

private void loadHeader(){
HorizontalPanel headerPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
HorizontalPanel linkPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
headerPanel.setWidth("950px");
headerPanel.setHeight("86px");

    Hyperlink contact = new Hyperlink(Item.CONTACT.getLabel(),
                   Item.CONTACT.getTarget());

contact.setWidth("94px");
contact.addStyleName(cssBundle.testCss().testTemplateLink());   
linkPanel.add(contact);
    linkPanel.setHeight("43px");

headerPanel.add(linkPanel);
DOM.setStyleAttribute(linkPanel.getElement(), "backgroundImage","url(menu.png)");
headerPanel.setCellVerticalAlignment(linkPanel,
                      HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
main.add(headerPanel, DockPanel.NORTH);
}
}
```

Comment: Provide some more specific code please...

Comment: @Onkar I've added some more code, I'm not sure if it's ok for you or maybe you need more code to see what's happening, in any case just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I added the following code to my Public Template

```
home.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
        home.addStyleName(cssBundle.testCss().
        contact.removeStyleName(cssBundle.testCss().
                  testTemplateLink2());
    }
    });

   contact.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
        home.removeStyleName(cssBundle.testCss().
                  testTemplateLink2());
        contact.addStyleName(cssBundle.testCss().
                    testTemplateLink2());
    }
    });
```

for each link and also my styles are:

```
    .Template-link
{
COLOR: #808080;
FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
LINE-HEIGHT: 43px;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
}

.Template-link a 
{
COLOR: #808080;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
VERTICAL-ALIGN:text-middle;
}

.Template-link2 
{
COLOR: #AB1E2C;
FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
LINE-HEIGHT: 43px;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
}

.Template-link2 a
{
COLOR: #AB1E2C;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
VERTICAL-ALIGN:text-middle;
}
```

I leave these methods and my solution just in case someonelse has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i think happening here is this,

If we use give "focus" to the Hyperlink, it now enters its :focus state(navigate to it using "Tab"). On clicking (or press space when has focus), the Hyperlink enters its (:active) state.

When you click (or press space on focus) on an element, you give it focus, which also gives the allusion that :focus and :active are the same. They are not the same. When clicked the button is in :focus:active state.

I see a missing declaration in the code that you have provided

```
.Template-link a:focus{}
```

Also try adding

```
.Template-link a:focus a:active{}
```

Comment: well that's what is happening, my a:focus stays on a:focus active, but I've tried with a:focus a:active and it doesn't change it's state...

I need it to stay with the same color as a:focus (while the user stays on the page until s/he clicks on another Hyperlink on the menu)

Comment: this will sound naive of me but try the order you are setting for the css...as in focus before active and focus active together after active ...also check using firebug if anything is overriding your css declarations